# Why does the following codes produce error on Google Colab but prefectly fine on Microsoft Azure?

Tags: scatter-plot, attributeerror

when i try to implement the following code using Google Colab, an attribute error pops up, does anyone have any idea of the reasons behind?

```
!pip install graphing
import graphing # Custom graphing code. See our GitHub repository for details

# Let's take a quick look at our data
graphing.scatter_2D(data, label_x="date", label_y="min_temperature", title="January Temperatures (°F)")
```

### ****The error:****
Requirement already satisfied: graphing in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (0.0.6)

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/plotly/express/_core.py in make_trace_kwargs(args, trace_spec, g, mapping_labels, sizeref)
276                         try:
--> 277                             position = args["custom_data"].index(col)
278                         except (ValueError, AttributeError, KeyError):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

Answer (score 0):

Scatter_2D attribute is not available at the moment,
you can try using below command

```
import plotly.express as px
px.scatter(data,x="date",y="min_temp",title='January Temparatures')
```